# How can I validate if a string is a string and not an integer in java?

Tags: java, validation, try-catch

I enter a list into a `JTextArea`, and when I push a button, it runs the method below. I need to check to see if `str[i+1]`, `str[i+2]` is a `String` and not an `int`.

```
public void readData(JTextArea input) {
    String[] str = input.getText().split("\n");
    for(int i =1; i< str.length; i= i+3) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            simulator.add(new Process(Integer.parseInt(str[i]), str[i+1],str[i+2])); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer only " +
                                str[i] + " is not an integer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is of course a string, since you are getting the text from a JTextArea.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a function that tries to parse the string into an `Integer` or a `Double` and return true if it succeeded, or return false is an exception was thrown during parsing. Parsing into a `Double` should be enough since all integer values are decimal values without the .0

```
public static boolean isNumber(String s) {
    try {  
        Double.parseDouble(s);
        /* Use Integer.parseInt(s) instead, if
           you want to check if the String s
           is an Integer */
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { // string is not a number
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can say `if(!isNumber(str))` to check if the `String` str is not a number.

Alternatively, you could make the `isNumber()` be a `isNotNumber()` by swapping the `return false` and `return true` statements.

If you don't want to use exceptions, a different approach would be the following. Since we know a valid number can only contain digits and at most 1 dot for decimal point, we can iterate through the string and check for each character:

- if it is not a digit and not a dot, return false
- if it is a dot but a dot was already found, return false
- otherwise it is valid number character and we do nothing

Here is a sample function:

```
public static boolean isNumber(String s) {
    int dotCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) != '.' && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        } else if(s.charAt(i) == '.') {
            if(dotCount == 1) {
                return false;
            }
            dotCount = 1;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:** based on @MadProgrammer's suggestions:

A more general approach that will accept values separated with commas such as `1,35` or any amount of spaces within the number string like with `123 456 . 333`.

**Approach:**

Iterate through the string and check for each character:

- if it is not a digit, dot, comma, or a space, return false
- if it is a dot or a comma but one of them was already found, return false
- otherwise it is valid number character and we do nothing

So the code would look something like:

```
public static boolean isNumber(String s) {
    int separatorCount = 0; // count dots and commas
    char currChar;
    s.trim();  // remove trailing and leading whitespace
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        currChar = s.charAt(i);
        if (currChar != '.' && currChar != ',' && currChar != ' '
                && !Character.isDigit(currChar)) {
            return false;
        } else if (currChar == '.' || currChar == ',') {
            if (separatorCount == 1) {
                return false;
            }
            separatorCount = 1;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another solution could use the `NumberFormat`'s `parse()` method. However, this method only checks the beginning of the string (for example, for `12.3.3` it will return `12.3`) so we have to return false if the returned string doesn't equal the input string as well as if the `ParseException` is thrown.

```
public static boolean isNumber(String s) {
    try {
        String newVal = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(s).toString();
        if (!newVal.equals(s)) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

***NOTE*:** All of the methods should probably have a check `if(s == null) { return false; }` for the input `String` s to prevent a `NullPointerException`

Comment: You could try using a `NumberFormat` instead of using the `isNumber` value...as an idea ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I assume this wouldn't work for every value. In the docs for NumberFormat.getInstance().parse() it says: `Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.` and if I parse `12.3.3` it doesn't cause an exception. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, it was just an off the head idea, haven't tested it myself, but it might save some work ;) - Mind you, a `DocumentFilter` on the text field itself, could solve all these problems ;)

Comment: Having tested it (now), `12.3.3` returns `12.3`, in those case you could check to see if the two values, when converted to `String` are the same...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just tested it and the parse() methods only check parts of the string. The test I mentioned in the previous comment accepts `12.3.3` as `12.3`. Of course, any suggestion from a Mad programmer must be appreciated :P

Comment: There's still no enough context to the question, is `A B C 123` a valid value or not?  I don't think there's any (major) problems with your approach, except you're not taking whitespace into account, for example `1, 000.00`...You could also be using `Character.isDigit` instead of the range check...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the suggestions, will test/add 'em now.

Answer (score 2):

Your rules are sparse, you don't specify if things like `,` or `.` are considered part of a number or not (`1, 000.01` for example), also, you don't define if the value is allowed to contain numerical values or not, but...

### You Could...

Try parsing each value (or the concatenation of the two) using `Integer.parseInt`, if they pass, then they are not `String` (or text) based values...

### You Could...

Verify each character within the `String` to see if it contains more than just digits, using something like `Character#isLetter`

### You Could...

Use a regular expression to determine if the value contain other content other than numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple regular expression to check if a string represents a number or not:-

```
String str = "12345";
System.out.println(str.matches("\\d+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems the best option. Here's a regex that will parse float and integers and currency values with comma as well.

```
 String numberRex = "^([\\d]*\\.*\\d*|[\\d,]*\\.*\\d*)$";
 "1234,455.43".matches(numberRex); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple test that asserts there is at least one non numeric char:

```
if (str.matches(".*[^\\d.].*"))
```

the regex translates as "somewhere in the input there's a character that's not a digit or a dot"